# Detectar a troca de uma imagem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal tenho uma tag img que tem um botao que carrega varias imagens para a pessoa escolher, assim que ele escolhe o src desta tag é alterado. Eu preciso detectar quando acontece esta alteração do src e mostrar um alerta. Tentei com o onchange mas não disparou, com o load deu certo mas ele disparou também no carregamento da pagina pois assim que a pagian carrega ali aparece uma imagem padrão.

```
$(".imagem").on("change", function(e){alert("alterou")});
```

Comment: Não é melhor fazer isso onde a imagem é alterada?

Comment: Se o utilizador escolhe quando alterar a `src` porque não usas esse evento/momento? queres saber o `load` dessa imagem quando a `src` mudar somente? Então podes juntar esse event handler que tens em cima > mudar a `src` > remover o event handler quando o `load` fôr chamado

Comment: @Sergio não consegui entender a sua explicação.

Comment: @Lucas eu realmente preciso verificar o change do SRC não tem como ser quando a imagem é alterada.

Comment: Como é o código de quando "a pessoa escolher"?

Comment: @Sergio esta num modal com uma galeria de imagens. Quando ele escolhe a imagem dispara este codigo: `$('#imagem'+coluna, window.parent.document).attr('src', arquivo);´

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo então consegues detetar aí quando a imagem troca e mostrar o alerta certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa registra o evento com o `load` após a pagina tiver sido carregada completamente:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.image').on('load', function() {
        alert('Imagem alterada');
    });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfcofnkm/)

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho @luciorubeens.